# Extracting Value of Key in Atom by Converting String to Symbol

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have an atom:

```
{:answer1 "yes", :answer2 "no", :answer3 "maybe"}
```

And I want to be able to use the variable x to extract the value of :answerx.

In my REPL, when I test out how to append to a string and then convert to symbol, this works:

```
(symbol (str ":answer" 2))
```

Result is :answer2. However, when I attempt to do this within the atom, I get a result of nil:

```
(get @answers-atom (symbol (str ":answer" 2)))
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Side note: the thing that you're calling an "atom" is actually a "map". You can store a map inside of an atom (as you seem to be doing here with `answers-atom`), but they are completely distinct concepts and in this case, the fact that you're using an atom is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you're mixing up symbols and keywords. For instance, in the map that you give at the beginning of your question, `:answer1`, `:answer2`, and `:answer3` are keywords, but `(symbol (str ":answer" 2))` is a symbol. To get a keyword, you need to instead use the [`keyword`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword) function:

```
(def m {:answer1 "yes" :answer2 "no" :answer3 "maybe"})

(get m (symbol (str ":answer" 2))) ;=> nil

(get m (keyword (str "answer" 2))) ;=> "no"
```

Comment: GAH! Thanks so much.